# phonegap for each platform should be created?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova

phonegap is cross-platform solution for mobile development. my question is for each platform i should create new project with phonegap and import my html/js/css? or there is a tool to generate other platforms code?

Comment: There is a PhoneGap Build service: https://build.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no tool for that.

You have to use the project templates for all devices you want to support and share the "www" folder for all the projects.

The main problem with this approach is that you have to implement all changes in the native code for each device... for example we had to change the start page in our project.

**edit**

Thank you for the hint @PeterMmm, did not know this =)

Answer (score 0):

As @PeterMmm has mentioned, the PhoneGap build service allows you to build for all the supported platforms "in the cloud". Currently it does not support custom plugins although I understand that is a planned feature.
So as long as you are using only stock PhoneGap API calls you should be OK to use the build service.